# Android: Error unable to implement image onclick listener on image in a list view

Tags: android

Hi there I am new to Android Programming

I have successfully created code which display a listview
In each listview, there is an image on the left hand side

Error: When I click on the image, I am unable to link it to another page

Please help me out 
Here is my code:

CustomAdapter.java

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   implements OnClickListener {
  private OnImageClickListener mListener;
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){ 


        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

        /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");

    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
         holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());
         holder.text1.setText(tempValues.getUrl());

             holder.image.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier
             ("com.example.customlistview24:drawable
             /"+tempValues.getImage(),null,null));


         vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));


         //Gabriel Code 28/01/2014
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (mListener != null) {
                    Log.v("234", "123");
                    mListener.onClick(v);


                }

            }


           });

                 //End of Code
              }
              return vi;
               }


              }

  public class CustomListViewAndroidExample extends Activity implements  

   OnImageClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new          

         Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleLockerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
   }



  public interface OnImageClickListener {
   public void onClick(View view); // Object data [Optional]
  }
```

Please help me out

Comment: add onItemClick listener for ListView

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, nothing happens when you tap on the image element because `mListener` is never set to a valid object.  So when the code:

```
if (mListener != null) {
    Log.v("234", "123");
    mListener.onClick(v);
}
```

is encountered, it skips over the block entirely and takes no action.

Comment: how do we set mListener to a valid object

Comment: mListener = new CustomListViewAndroidExample();

I get a java.lang.NullPointer Exception when i do that 
Pleas help